# Why does my joi validation errors show in terminal but not in postman for nested document, but does show for flat document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

Can someone please point out my error...
When I run the below, the error message appears in the vs.code terminal, but not in postman. All I get is "message": "Error adding pack". If I change all the below to suit my last code block i.e not nested, then I get the appropriate message in postman.

pack.js

```
const packSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    packDetail: {
      packNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [6, "Must be longer than 5 chars"],
        maxlength: 6,
      },
      jobDescription: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 100,
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Pack = mongoose.model("pack", packSchema);

module.exports = Pack;
```

packRoutes.js

```
const packValidation = require("./../controllers/pack/pack.validator");
const {
  addPack,
  getPacks,
  getPack,
  updatePack,
  deletePack,
} = require("./../controllers/pack/pack.controller");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getPacks);
router.get("/:id", getPack);
router.post("/", addPack);
router.patch("/:id", updatePack);
router.delete("/:id", deletePack);

module.exports = router;
```

pack.validator.js

```
const errorFunction = require("../../utils/errorFunction");

const validation = joi.object({
  packDetail: {
    packNumber: joi.string().alphanum().min(6).max(6).trim(true).required(),
    jobDescription: joi.string().min(5).max(100).trim(true).required(),
  },
});

const packValidation = async (req, res, next) => {
  const payload = {
    packDetail: {
      packNumber: req.body.packDetail.packNumber,
      jobDescription: req.body.packDetail.jobDescription,
    },
  };

  const { error } = validation.validate(payload);
  if (error) {
    res.status(406);
    return res.json(
      errorFunction(true, `Error in pack data : ${error.message}`)
    );
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

module.exports = packValidation;
```

pack.controller.js

```
const Pack = require("../../models/pack");
const errorFunction = require("../../utils/errorFunction");

const addPack = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const existingPack = await Pack.findOne({
      packDetail: { packNumber: req.body.packDetail.packNumber.trim() },
    }).lean(true);

    if (existingPack) {
      res.status(403);
      return res.json(errorFunction(true, "Pack already exists"));
    } else {
      const newPack = await Pack.create({
        packDetail: {
          packNumber: req.body.packDetail.packNumber.trim(),
          jobDescription: req.body.packDetail.jobDescription,
        },
      });

      if (newPack) {
        res.status(201);
        return res.json(errorFunction(false, "Pack created", newPack));
      } else {
        res.status(403);
        return res.json(errorFunction(true, "Error creating pack"));
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400);
    console.log(error);
    return res.json(errorFunction(true, "Error adding pack"));
  }
};

module.exports = {
  addPack,
  getPacks,
  getPack,
  updatePack,
  deletePack,
};
```

sample un-nested....

```
const joi = require("joi");
const errorFunction = require("../../utils/errorFunction");

const validation = joi.object({
  code: joi.string().alphanum().min(6).max(6).trim(true).required(),
  name: joi.string().min(3).max(50).trim(true).required(),
  description: joi.string().min(5).max(100).trim(true).required(),
  sequence: joi.number().integer().required(),
  isActive: joi.boolean().default(true),
});

const departmentValidation = async (req, res, next) => {
  const payload = {
    code: req.body.code.trim(),
    name: req.body.name.trim(),
    description: req.body.description.trim(),
    sequence: req.body.sequence,
    isActive: req.body.isActive,
  };

  const { error } = validation.validate(payload);
  if (error) {
    res.status(406);
    return res.json(
      errorFunction(true, `Error in department data : ${error.message}`)
    );
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

module.exports = departmentValidation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh! forgot to add "packValidation" to router.post("/", addPack); in packRoutes.js

updated code should read...

```
router.post("/",packValidation, addPack);
```